# Force a usercontrol on web page to reinitialize iteself

Tags: c#, asp.net

There are 2 user controls, one is inside the other.

These controls are located on an .aspx.

One control is a modal popup the other is a custom search control (the search control is inside the modal popup).

After a user has completed a search and closes the form, the next time the popup opens (for the same user) the old values are still present.

How can I clear the values out each time the form loads?

Edit:
Is it possible to capture the popup closing event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out there is no method on the control to clear out the values on the control.

So what I have to do is create the method on the search control to clear out the control and create a method on the popup control to capture the popup open or close event to trigger the clear method.

At first I wasn't going to be able to change the control..since explaining that this was the only way to solve the issue the control can be changed..thank god!  And since the method is not going to be a default option it won't affect anywhere else the controls are used.

Answer (score 3):

You could clear all the values using javascript- here is an example using jquery:

http://beckelman.net/post/2008/09/24/Clear-Input-Fields-in-an-AjaxControlToolkit-ModalPopup-When-Cancel-is-Clicked.aspx

Comment: Sounds good.. do you know if that would work similarly for a group of asp:RegularExpressionValidator's?  I need to reset their values also, set them to true atleast.

Comment: well, it would have been nice if his example worked the way it was supposed to.  His example did not do what it stated..so I guess this example is not accurate..

Comment: really all the example is doing is clearing input fields. More simply, you could do something like this:  

$('#myTexboxId').val('');

For each input you wanted to clear.  It gets more complicated with asp.net automatic ids, but that is another issue entirely.

Resetting the validators is just as easy:

$('.validatorErrorMessageClass').remove();

Comment: well thats my main problem is that I have to get the id's from the usercontrol.  I know how to clear values...what I don't know how to do and what I'm asking for help on is how clear values in a user control when I can't make changes to the user control itself.

Answer (score 3):

For one of the applications I currently maintain we use a recursive function to reset all the fields within the control. I have added it below but remember it is used in a C# windows application not a web application. Hope it helps.

```
public static void ResetFields(Control.ControlCollection pageControls)
    {
        foreach (Control contl in pageControls) 
        {
            var strCntName = (contl.GetType()).Name;
            switch (strCntName)
            {
                case "Button":
                    contl.Enabled = true;
                    break;
                case "TextBox":
                    var txtSource = (TextBox)contl;
                    txtSource.Text = "";
                    break;
                case "ListBox":
                    var lstSource = (ListBox)contl;
                    lstSource.SelectedIndex = -1;
                    lstSource.Enabled = true;
                    break;
                case "ComboBox":
                    var cmbSource = (ComboBox)contl;
                    cmbSource.SelectedIndex = -1;
                    cmbSource.Enabled = true;
                    break;
                case "DataGridView":
                    var dgvSource = (DataGridView)contl;    
                    dgvSource.Rows.Clear();
                    break;
                case "CheckBox":
                    var chkSource = (CheckBox)contl;
                    chkSource.Checked = false;
                    chkSource.Enabled = true;
                    break;
            }
            ResetFields(contl.Controls);
        }
    }
```

Comment: that would be a great solution, but I don't want to postback when the popup is closed

Comment: @Lee could this not be used when the form is loaded? Just to clear each field

Comment: This is not want to happen everywhere else the control is used.  Otherwise this would be great

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this user control has some client side JS code associated with it, I would modify the control to clear out its search values and results upon closing the modal popup.

This will ensure when the modal popup is reopened its in the correct state for new searches.

`Sys.Application.add_init` wouldn't work in this case since that will only run once when the page is loaded.

You need to write some new JS when the model popup is cancelled or closed.

Modifying the control will be your best option here so all other pages that use this control can take advantage of the new reset functionality.

It's difficult to give you any more specific information at this time without knowing the structure of your page, usercontrol and any existing javascript.

Comment: the main issue with that is the control, on most of the other pages, is not contained in a modalpopup (i'll edit post to reflect this), it's directly on the page.  And I don't want to clear the results in the other areas this control is used